# Services not responding

Tags: service, windows-sbs-2008, not-responding

A SBS 2008 server that I manage suddenly acts very strange. After a scheduled reboot I noticed that the server is almost unmanagable. Some services (e.g. Fax, RAS) can't be started, the services.msc is not responding (empty window, "Not responding" in the title), I can't start or shut down services using Task Manager (it tells me they're in the process of starting/shutting down but they never do).
I suspect a recent Update, but since Windows Update is also a service I can't access that either to check. Same with Windows Backup.
Rebooting the server also does not help (but takes forever, don't know if that was the case before).
I noticed when logging off it always tells me it's installing updates (phase 3 of 3) so that's why I suspect a recent update.
What's more strange is that file sharing and Exchange are working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your event log say anything interesting?  (And if the SBS 2008 server is the only DC on the network, then yes, rebooting will take forever.)

Comment: No, the log seems normal afaik. Atm I'm killing one service at a time to see if I can find the culprit. Slow going...